# Как сделать сервер с библиотекой socket глобальным Python?

Tags: python, сервер, сокет

Начал я изучать такую штучку, как сокеты. Взор мой пал на библиотеку socket. Я посмотрел, как там создается сервер, скопипастил код и вроде всё хорошо, сервер работает, но тут я понял, что хочу сделать именно удаленный сервер, чтобы для отправления запроса не требовалось нахождение клиента и сервера в одной локальной сети. Погуглив, я наткнулся на ответ, в котором говорилось:"*Надо просто сделать себе статичный айпи, а дальше всё, как и было*". Сделал я и это, но не помогло: когда с клиента отправляется запрос - он просто не доходит до сервера (проходит секунд 20 и на клиенте выдает ошибку, мол, время вышло, а ответа нет). Помогите разобраться, может, я чего-то не понимаю, либо сам питон не особо подходит для этого.

вот код сервера и клиента (шаблоны. Они будут дорабатываться, конечно):

````
# server.py
import socket

print('Server started')
while True:
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(('000.000.000.000', 9090)) # my static IP
    sock.listen(1)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print('connected:', addr)
    text = 'запрос принят'
    conn.send(text.encode())
    conn.close()

# client.py
import socket

while True:
    sock = socket.socket()
    inp = input('Введите сообщение: ')
    try:
        sock.connect(('000.000.000.000', 9090)) # static IP
        sock.send(str(inp).encode())
    except:
        print('Error!')
    else:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        sock.close()
        print(data.decode())```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе потребуется узнать свой статический ip [сайт для этого](https://2ip.ru), далее пробросить порт на роутере (зайти в админку роутера -> переадресация портов). В программах указать ip и порт, который ты переадресовал.

```
sock.bind(('', PORT))
sock.connect(('IP', PORT))
```